# Ordenamiento de valores por filas de una matriz en Python

Tags: python, matrices

Estoy tratando de extraer los índices de ordenamiento por filas de la matriz pero Python no me ordena los datos correctamente, ¿Alguien me podría explicar por qué?
Necesito que cada valor en cada vector fila me arroje el indice de ordenamiento
Ejm: Fila 1 sería [4, 1, 2, 0, 3]

```
import numpy as np

Pj = np.array([[47,   15,    38,     10,     38], 
      [23,   20,    39,     46,     24],
      [38,   10,    26,     36,     40],
      [27,   27,    29,     27,     17],
      [12,   31,    35,     40,     49],
      [22,   47,    31,     23,     21],
      [27,   36,    39,     16,     16],
      [19,   24,    29,     44,     13],
      [17,   31,    27,     13,     26],
      [15,   31,    39,     20,     41]])

pj_sort_aux = np.argsort(Pj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.argsort` da la posición de cada elemento. P.ej. `np.argsort([47, 15, 38, 10, 38])` da `[3, 1, 2, 4, 0]`. Es decir, el elemento más pequeño tiene posición `3`, el siguiente posición `1`, etc.

Un truco para tener el rango de cada elemento, sería llamar `np.argsort` dos veces.  `np.argsort(np.argsort([47, 15, 38, 10, 38]))` da `[4, 1, 2, 0, 3]`. El primer elemento (`47`) tiene el rango `4` en el array ordenado, etc.

El mismo truco funciona con la matriz:

```py
np.argsort(np.argsort(Pj))
```

resultado:

```
array([[4, 1, 2, 0, 3],
       [1, 0, 3, 4, 2],
       [3, 0, 1, 2, 4],
       [1, 2, 4, 3, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 4, 3, 2, 0],
       [2, 3, 4, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
       [1, 4, 3, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 3, 1, 4]])
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!